# Can someone explain the meaning of this 'typedef'?

Tags: c, typedef

Can someone explain this typedef please?

```
typedef void (*_sig_func_ptr)(int);
```

Understanding its meaning seems critical to answering my question:
[MPICH2 compilation issue using Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915812/mpich2-compilation-issue-using-cygwin#comment20932150_14915812)

Comment: It's a prototype for a function that has one `int` parameter and returns `void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it declares a type which is a function pointer which takes an int and returns void

can be used like :-

```
void blah(int x)
{
}


_sig_func_ptr ptr;

ptr = blah;  // make ptr point to blah

ptr(12);     // now we can call blah by using the function pointer
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax of the `typedef` of a function pointer type.

Here `_sig_func_ptr` is an alias for the type `void (*)(int)`.

An object of type `_sig_func_ptr` is a pointer to a function with one `int` parameter and that returns nothing.